# Map ctrl to super in GNOME

Tags: gnome, keyboard-layout

i'm running Ubuntu Precise, and I want to perform the following remapping, preferably through Gnome's "System Settings > Keyboard > Layout > Options" menu (though if that's not possible I could fall back to xmodmap):

1. Remap Caps Lock to CTRL (done)
2. Remap Left Ctrl to Super (doesn't seem to be an option for it in the menu, though there is a "remap left ctrl to meta")

Ideally, I'm trying not to bypass Gnome's configurations, so if there is some way to accomplish step 2 above using gconfeditor rather than disabling gnome's keyboard remapping and just doing the whole thing through xmodmap, I'd like to know it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Gnome on Ubuntu Precise, or are you perhaps using Unity (the default) on Ubuntu Precise, and mistakenly calling it Gnome?

Either way (I think), I believe Xmodmap will be your best bet. See  [my answer on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131900/how-do-i-switch-the-command-key-and-control-key-on-a-macbook-pro-12-04).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here.

Comment: i'm using gnome-panel + xmonad